Conditional formatting in table of contents (toc) with ifx
I am trying to format the appearance of table of contents in a book document. Below is an example of what I want to achieve.

So far, below is a depiction of the extent I progressed with a MWE:
\documentclass[10pt, 
]{book}    

\usepackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}                 % force newer (and safer) 
                                                  % LaTeX commands

%% Page dimensions
\usepackage[portrait, 
    a5paper, 
    hmargin=0.75in,
    vmargin={0.88in, 0.94in},
]{geometry}                                       % control page layout

%% Fonts & languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % type Unicode characters 
                                                  % directly from the keyboard
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                          % font encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}                       % multi-language support
\usepackage[protrusion=true, 
    expansion=true, 
    final, 
    babel,
]{microtype}                                      % improves word spacing
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Lists & tables
\usepackage{enumitem}                             % more list formatting options
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}           % text justification

\usepackage[pdftex,
    bookmarks,
    colorlinks,
    breaklinks,
    hypertexnames=false,
]{hyperref}                                       % coloured hyperlinks in pdf  

%% TOC customisation & formatting
\usepackage{titlesec}                             % section formatting
\usepackage{titletoc}                             % TOC formatting 
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\contentsname{%        % format title of TOC
    \Large\centering CONTENTS}}                   % to be used with babel
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\scriptsize
    \rlap{\hspace{-1.70em}PAGE}\par}              % add page above page numbers
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}       % Roman numbers for chapter
\titlecontents{chapter}[2pc]                      % format the appearance of
  {%                                              % TOC entries 
        \addvspace{0.5pc}%                                                          
        \filleft%  
        \normalfont%
  }
  {%
        \centering%
    \large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} %
        \thecontentslabel%
    \\*[1.0pc]%
    \footnotesize
  }
  {}
  {\titlerule*[3pc]{.}\normalsize\contentspage}
  [\addvspace{1.0pc}]   
     
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom{}
\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter*{PREFACE}% 
\label{cha:PREFACE}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}
\fi

\mainmatter{}

\chapter{FIRST CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:FIRST_CHAPTER}

\chapter{SECOND CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:SECOND_CHAPTER}

\chapter{THIRD CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:THIRD_CHAPTER}

\chapter{FOURTH CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:FOURTH_CHAPTER}
\end{document}


which results in

However, the PAGE is above CHAPTER I instead of in between CHAPTER I and FIRST CHAPTER. So, I tried the following using conditional expressions, \ifx...\fi, which I am not fully comfortable with yet
\titlecontents{chapter}[2pc]
    {%
        \addvspace{0.5pc}%
        \filleft%
        \normalfont%
    }
    {%
        \centering%
        \large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} %
        \thecontentslabel%
        \ifx{\romannumeral 1}\value{\thechapter}%
          \\*[0.10pc]%
          {~\hfill\scriptsize\rlap{\hspace{-1.70em}PAGE}}%
          \\*[0.10pc]%
        \else
          \\*[1.0pc]%
        \fi
        \footnotesize%
    }
    {}
    {\titlerule*[3pc]{.}\normalsize\contentspage}  
    [\addvspace{1.0pc}]

This results in errors. Further, I am using roman numeral chapter numbers and do not know if I should be using \ifnum...\fi construct instead. Please let me know.

you shouldn't add formatting instructions like \centering or \large to commands like \contentsname and \thechapter.

\ifx{\romannumeral compares the token { to the token \romannumeral which is only true if you previously did \let\romannumeral={

so the following } is a mis-matched breace as the iopening brace was consumed by the test.

@DavidCarlisle, I tried removing the { and }. I used \ifx\romannumeral 1\value{\thechapter} so that only chapter I gets the PAGE but conditional seems to be always false.

\ifx\romannumeral 1 tests the token \romannumeral with the catcode 12 token 1 so is only true if you previously did \let\romannumeral=1

I honestly can not guess what you intended \ifx{\romannumeral 1}\value{\thechapter}% to do (and you do not say) so I can only tell you what it does, not what you should change it to.  Apart from the ifx which you definitely do not want, \value{\thechapter}  will generate errors for any normal definitions of \value and \thechapter  deleting it would remove the errors but I don't know what you intended to happen.

I want to add PAGE title above page numbers. Not at the topmost psotions but only between CHAPTER I and FIRST CHPTER in the toc. I intended to do it using a ifx...\if conditional where I was trying to test if \thechapter macro is \romannumeral 1`.

the test would be \ifnum 1=\value{chapter} but it seems a strange way of setting up the toc.

the position of Page in your second image is far more logical than its position in your first (and it's not really needed at all as the numbers are obviously page numbers from the context)

I tried \ifnum 1=\value{chapter} but that did not work. The conditional seems to evaluate to false for all values.

oh sorry yes of course the table of contents is before chapter 1 so the chapter counter is 0 for all entries.  I would simply remove the test.

@DavidCarlisle, thank you for your time much appreciated! I discarded conditional statements and used vspace instead.

I've always wondered why some thesis regulations require specifying that those are page numbers. What else could they be? Do those academic institutions believe that readers of theses by their students are idiots?

@UlrikeFischer, please see my response to the your similar comment to my own answer below. I am not entirely able to grasp your concerns here given that I have followed those practices based on the examples from LaTex packages. Moreover, it is not informative when what should be done instead is not suggested. It will be of great use when the alternatives or rather the right path ahead is laid.

After some fidgeting, I discarded going down the conditional expression route and added some positive and negative space (using vspace) near the title of toc. Below is the MWE
\documentclass[10pt, 
]{book}    

\usepackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}                 % force newer (and safer) 
                                                  % LaTeX commands

%% Page dimensions
\usepackage[portrait, 
    a5paper, 
    hmargin=0.75in,
    vmargin={0.88in, 0.94in},
]{geometry}                                       % control page layout

%% Fonts & languages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % type Unicode characters 
                                                  % directly from the keyboard
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                          % font encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}                       % multi-language support
\usepackage[protrusion=true, 
    expansion=true, 
    final, 
    babel,
]{microtype}                                      % improves word spacing
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Lists & tables
\usepackage{enumitem}                             % more list formatting options
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}           % text justification

\usepackage[pdftex,
    bookmarks,
    colorlinks,
    breaklinks,
    hypertexnames=false,
]{hyperref}                                       % coloured hyperlinks in pdf  

%% TOC customisation & formatting
\usepackage{titlesec}                             % section formatting
\usepackage{titletoc}                             % TOC formatting 
\addto\captionsenglish{\def\contentsname{%        % format title of TOC
    \Large\centering CONTENTS}}                   % to be used with babel
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}       % Roman numbers for chapter
\titlecontents{chapter}[2pc]                      % format the appearance of
  {%                                              % TOC entries 
        \addvspace{-2.00pc}%
        \filleft%  
        \normalfont%
  }
  {%
        \centering%
    \large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} %
        \thecontentslabel%
    \\*[1.0pc]%
    \footnotesize
  }
  {}
  {\titlerule*[3pc]{.}\normalsize\contentspage}
    [\addvspace{3.50pc}]
     
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom{}
\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter*{PREFACE}% 
\label{cha:PREFACE}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{2.0pc}}               % add space after TOC title
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\scriptsize
    \rlap{\hspace{-1.70em}PAGE}\par}              % add page above page numbers
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}
\fi

\mainmatter{}

\chapter{FIRST CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:FIRST_CHAPTER}

\chapter{SECOND CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:SECOND_CHAPTER}

\chapter{THIRD CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:THIRD_CHAPTER}

\chapter{FOURTH CHAPTER}%
\label{cha:FOURTH_CHAPTER}
\end{document}


Which resulted in the following

Edit:
As per the suggestion of @UlrikeFischer, I removed \centering from the redefinition of \thechapter.

you shouldn't add formatting instructions like \centering or \large to commands like \contentsname and \thechapter. These commands are used many places and not in everyone \centering makes sense. You are only asking for trouble if you misuse them to adjust the formatting.

@UlrikeFischer, it would be nice of you if you could be more specific about the alternatives. In fact, titlesec and titletoc documentation has examples where formatting based on \thechapter and \contentsname is done fairly often (for ex. section 6.5). And since I am using both these packages, I have done the same. However, when I tried to change \centering to \center (ragged2e package) that only worked for \titlecontents from titletoc. I would appreciate if you can point to proper alternatives.

The titletoc docu does not add \centering to \thechapter. It only changes the numbering to Roman. Try the following document. Check and count in how many places the "blub!" appear (do not forget the bookmarks). And then consider if you are sure that your \centering is wanted in all these places and won't do harm there. \documentclass{book} \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref} \renewcommand\thechapter{blub!\arabic{chapter}} \pagestyle{headings} \begin{document} \tableofcontents \chapter{A}\label{chap} \section{A section} \newpage\ref{chap} \end{document}.

@UlrikeFischer. Thank you for the MWE, I appreciate your patience and time. About the "blub!", I checked it and for my purposes it is not a bother. Now, however, If you are saying that one should never use \centering and or \large with \thechapter then, on the contrary, there are cases in the documentation of titlesec and titletoc (for ex. page 23, appendix). This is one of the few I have come across. On the other hand, if your concern is directed more towards the titletoc and toc then please point me towards the right direction.

I am looking for the right way to achieve what I want to achieve, if not immediately, but for the future.

titlesec uses \centering with \thechapter, but not inside the definition. In titlesec there is a \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}  but there is not a \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\centering\Roman{chapter}}. So please read the titlesec documentation more carefully and uses its examples.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for clarifying, that was not made clear so far and as can be clearly seen, it only furthered my misinterpretation and subsequent confusion. I sincerely thank you for being nice and constructive.

@UlrikeFischer, I have updated my answer accordingly. Thank you.
